# CSS visited, hover and active is not working

Tags: css

```
  a: link {
        color: #000099;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

  a: visited {
        color: #000099;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

a: hover{
    color: #33cccc;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a: active{
    color: #000099;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'm using the code above in my css but only a:link is working and the rest is not.

I've already link it correctly to my html file.

I'm using sublime text 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces after the colons. The pseudo-class is always attached to the element/class/id without spaces.

```css
a:link {
 color: #000099;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
 color: #000099;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #33cccc;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
 color: #000099;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```